# If S $\subseteq G$ and $g \in G$, then $g N_G(S) g^{-1} = N_G ( g S g^{-1})$ and $g C_G(S) g^{-1} = C_G(gS g^{-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove the following statement

If S $\subseteq G$ and $g \in G$, then $g N_G(S) g^{-1} = N_G ( g S g^{-1})$ and $g C_G(S) g^{-1} = C_G(gS g^{-1})$

where $N_G(S) = \{ g \in G| g S g^{-1} = S\}$ 
and $C_G(S) = \{ g \in G| g s g^{-1} = s, \forall s \in S\}$

i tried to show it by its definition of $N_G(S)$ and $C_G(S)$, but

---

with the aid of @David Hill, i made a answer for this statement.

1. $g N_G (S) g^{-1} \subset N_G(g SG^{-1})$

let $x \in g N_G(S)g^{-1}$, $i.e$, $x=gyg^{-1}$ for some $y \in N_G(S)$, 
want to see $x \in N_G(gSg^{-1})$, i.e $x (gSg^{-1}) \in g S g^{-1}$.

\begin{align}
x (g S g^{-1}) x^{-1} = g y g^{-1} g s g^{-1} g y^{-1} g^{-1} = g y S y^{-1} g^{-1} = g S g^{-1}
\end{align}
Since $y\in N_G(S)$, $y S y^{-1} \in N_G(S)$.

2. $N_G(g S g^{-1}) \subset g N_G(S) g^{-1}$
   Let $x \in N_G(gSg^{-1})$, want to see $x \in gN_G(S)g^{-1}$, $i.e$, $g^{-1} x g \in N_G(S)$ $i.e$, $(g^{-1} x g) S (g^{-1} x g)^{-1} \in S$

\begin{align}
g^{-1} x g S g^{-1} x^{-1} g = g^{-1} (xgS g^{-1}x^{-1}) g = g^{-1}(g S g^{-1} ) g = S
\end{align}
since $x \in N_G(gSg^{-1})$, $x (g Sg^{-1}) x^{-1} = g S g^{-1}$.

Thus $gN_G(S)g^{-1} = N_G(g S g^{-1})$.

Now for the center parts,

1. $g C_G(S) g^{-1} \subset C_G(g S g^{-1})$

Let $x \in g C_G(S)g^{-1}$, $i.e$, $x=gyg^{-1}$ for some $y \in C_G(S)$,

want to see $x\in g C_G(S) g^{-1}$, $i.e$, $g^{-1}x g \in C_G(S)$

\begin{align}
g^{-1} x g = g^{-1} g y g g^{-1} = y \in C_G(S)
\end{align}

Thus $x \in g C_G(S) g^{-1}$

2. $C_G(gSg^{-1}) \subset g C_G(S) g^{-1}$

Let $x \in C_G(g S g^{-1})$, want to see $x \in g C_G(S) g^{-1}$. $i.e$, $g^{-1} x g \in C_G(S)$, $i.e$, for all $s \in S$, $(g^{-1} x g) s (g^{-1} x g)^{-1} = s$.

\begin{align}
g^{-1} x g s (g^{-1} x g)^{-1} = g^{-1} (x g s g^{-1} x^{-1}) g 
= g^{-1} g S g^{-1} g = s
\end{align}
since $x \in C_G(g Sg^{-1})$, for all $a \in gSg^{-1}$, $xax^{-1}=a$. 
Thus $x \in g C_G(S)g^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi, could you please tell us what happened when you tried to show this using the definitions of $N_G(S)$ and $C_G(S)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First show that $gN_G(S)g^{-1}\subset N_G(gSg^{-1})$: If $x\in gN_G(S)g^{-1}$, then $x=gyg^{-1}$ for some $y\in N_G(S)$. Therefore
\begin{align}
x(gSg^{-1})x^{-1}&=(gyg^{-1})(gSg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(gyg^{-1})(gSg^{-1})(gy^{-1}g^{-1})\\
&=gy(g^{-1}g)S(g^{-1}g)y^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=g(ySy^{-1})g^{-1}\\
&=gSg^{-1}
\end{align}
so $x\in N_G(gSg^{-1})$.

Now show $N_G(gSg^{-1})\subset gN_G(S)g^{-1}$: If $x\in N_G(gSg^{-1})$, then
\begin{align}
gSg^{-1}&=x(gSg^{-1})x^{-1}\\
&=(gg^{-1})x(gSg^{-1})x^{-1}(gg^{-1})\\
&=g((g^{-1}xg)S(g^{-1}x^{-1}g))g^{-1}\\
&=g((g^{-1}xg)S(g^{-1}xg)^{-1})g^{-1}\\
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
S&=g^{-1}(gSg^{-1})g\\
&=g^{-1}g((g^{-1}xg)S(g^{-1}xg)^{-1})g^{-1}g\\
&=(g^{-1}xg)S(g^{-1}xg)^{-1}.
\end{align}$$
It follows that $g^{-1}xg\in N_G(S)$, or $x\in gN_G(S)g^{-1}$, as required.

The other statement is similar.