# Problem 4.3.4 from Dummit and Foote's book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, suppose that $S\subset G$ and $g\in G$ then $gN_G(S)g^{-1}=N_G(gSg^{-1})$ and $C_G(g^{-1}Sg)=g^{-1}C_G(S)g$.

$N_G(S):= \{ g\in G \mid gsg^{-1}\in S\}$.
So $s\in N_G(S)\Leftrightarrow gsg^{-1}\in S$.
How to finish this simple exrecise?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262383/104041).